# Pressure Change in Supersonic Wind Tunnel

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, shock-waves

As far as I know, the total pressure changes across a shock wave.  How is this possible if you are in the atmosphere and atmospheric pressure isn't changing?  Is energy lost due to entropy in generated through a shock wave, and therefore a loss of pressure occurs?

Comment: I answered under the assumption that you were confused about the source of the pressure change across a shock.  If that is what you were asking, then try rewording the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The scalar [pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure) changes across a shock wave in a [collisional fluid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_theory) because of the conservation of momentum and energy flux.  This is one of the [conservation equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservation_law) in the [Rankine-Hugoniot relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rankine-Hugoniot_conditions) which govern the thermodynamics of shock waves.

The [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy) increases because the change in bulk kinetic energy across the shock wave is [irreversibly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreversible_process) converted into random kinetic energy (i.e., [heat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat)).

Note that irreversibility is required for a shock wave to form in the first place.  Without irreversibility, a [nonlinearly steepening wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_wave#Shock_waves_due_to_nonlinear_steepening) would break kind of like [water waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_wave) do on a windy day.